# Empty space on the map in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, polygon, ggmap

There is a empty space on the map. The data is ivalable for those regions. What could be the Problem?

[image: Empty Space]

[The data before merge](https://www.dropbox.com/s/1tyxr0athq2kcn6/summery_table_GG_R.xlsx?dl=0)

Geo Data for Germany:

```
URL <- "https://biogeo.ucdavis.edu/data/gadm3.6/Rsp/gadm36_DEU_1_sp.rds"
```

germany <- readRDS(url(URL))

germany <- fortify(germany)

```
df_Karte_ratio %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = long, y = lat, 
                              group = group, fill = ratio_fl_arzt
                              ))+
  geom_polygon(col = "black") +
  coord_map()+
  facet_grid(~EP01_KJP02_BEIDE03_PSM_04_20)+
  labs(title = "Fälle-Arzt Verhältnis")+
  theme_map()+
  theme(
    legend.position  = "right",
    #legend.direction = "horizontal",
    legend.title = element_blank())+
   scale_fill_continuous_sequential(palette = "BluYl")
```

Sadly I could not find any information about this issue

Comment: Could you please share some reproducible data using `dput`? So we can help you better.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: Thanks for your response - I just edited the question.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the data for those regions is not available or has not been included in the data frame that is being plotted. This could be due to a variety of reasons, such as incomplete data collection or data that has been intentionally excluded for some reason. In any case, the empty space on the map is likely due to a lack of data for those regions.

Comment: Empty space appears only while I am using facet_grid